# How to add cmake project to another cmake project as library?

Tags: c++, cmake

I have been researching over hours but I still couldn't solve my problem.

This is Cmakelist of ProjectA. It perfectly works:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(CMAKE_INCLUDE_CURRENT_DIR ON)
project(ProjectA C CXX)
add_executable(ProjectA ${SOURCE_FILES_ProjectA})
target_link_libraries(ProjectA hts ${ZLIB} pthread)
target_compile_definitions(ProjectA PUBLIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION=\"${VERSION_STRING}\")
```

Now I want to add ProjectA to ProjectB as library but I got following error at first:

> add_executable cannot create target "ProjectA" because another
>     target with the same name already exists.  The existing target is a static
>     library created in source directory

Then, I changes cmakelist of projectB as below. Now makefile is created but it doesn't work. (I removed set(source_files) for simplicity)

ProjectB cmakelist:

```
include_directories(
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/
${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/ProjectA)
add_library(ProjectA STATIC lib/ProjectA/src})
target_include_directories(ProjectA PUBLIC lib/ProjectA)
set_target_properties(ProjectA PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)

add_executable(ProjectB ${SOURCE_FILES})
target_link_libraries(ProjectB hts ${ZLIB} ProjectA pthread)
target_compile_definitions(ProjectB PUBLIC -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -DVERSION=\"${VERSION_STRING}\")
```

Can you correct my cmakelist files, I am really lost in cmake syntax.

Comment: How do you convert an executable to a library ? Do you comment the `main` function ?

Comment: Should I? What do you suggest? ProjectA is a git submodule and it also works as standalone application.

Comment: I don't know your specific case, I was just wondering how you handled that. In your case, I think we need a little more information. For example, you say `it doesn't work` which is not at all describing what happens. Could you show us the CMake error, please ? And, when do you get the error you quoted ? We don't have the corresponding code. (But this specific error is quite explicit : `ProjectA` is the name of a library so it can't **also** be the name of the executable.

Comment: Hey @Ninetainedo you are right about this. So right now I solve my problem by defining **file(GLOB MyLibSrc lib/ProjectA/*.cpp)** and add_library func. Can you recommend some cmake tutorial? I specially want to learn diff between target, link and add library functions.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the official documentation for commands you want to learn more about. For instance, [this is the target_link_libraries documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/target_link_libraries.html) take a look at it and you should understand it better. I'm available if you want precisions about something in particular. You can find me on [Twitter](https://twitter.com/telokis) or here in the comments.